# Matplotlib animate space vs time plot

Tags: animation, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently working on traffic jams analysis and was wondering if there's a way to animate the generation of a plot of such jams.

A plot of this things grow from up to the lower end of the figure, each 'row' is a time instance. The horizontal axis is just the road indicating at each point the position of each vehicle and, with a certain numeric value, the velocity of it. So applying different colors to different velocities, you get a plot that shows how a jam evolves through time in a given road.

My question is, how can I use matplotlib  to generate an animation of each instance of the road in time to get such a plot?

The plot is something like this:

[image]

I'm simulating a road with vehicles with certain velocities through time, so I wish  to animate a plot showing how the traffic jams evolve...

EDIT:

I add some code to make clear what I'm already doing

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc

plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = u'/usr/bin/ffmpeg'

# model params
vmax = 5
lenroad = 50
prob = 0.4

# sim params
numiters = 10

# traffic model
def nasch():
    gaps = np.full(road.shape, -1)
    road_r4 = np.full(road.shape, -1)
    for n,x in enumerate(road):
        if x > -1:
            d = 1
            while road[(n+d) % len(road)] < 0:
                d += 1
            d -= 1
            gaps[n] = d

    road_r1 = np.where(road!=-1, np.minimum(road+1, vmax), -1)
    road_r2 = np.where(road_r1!=-1, np.minimum(road_r1, gaps), -1)
    road_r3 = np.where(road_r2!=-1, np.where(np.random.rand() < prob, np.maximum(road-1, 0), road), -1)
    for n,x in enumerate(road_r3):
        if x > -1:
            road_r4[(n+x) % len(road_r3)] = x

    return road_r4

def plot_nasch(*args):
    road = nasch()
    plot.set_array([road])
    return plot,

# init road
road = np.random.randint(-10, vmax+1, [lenroad])
road = np.where(road>-1, road, -1)

# simulate
fig  = plt.figure()
plot = plt.imshow([road], cmap='Pastel2', interpolation='nearest')
for i in range(numiters):
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plot_nasch, frames=100, interval=500, blit=True)
    plt.show()
```

And I get  the following figure, just one road instead of each road painted at the bottom of the previous one:

[image]

Comment: Yes it's definitely possible with matplotlib. You would put your simulation results in a numpy array, show it with `imshow` and animate it, using `FuncAnimation`. There are enough examples around for each of the steps involved.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest in fact that's what I was trying to do, problem is that every time I use FuncAnimation the plotted road just overrides the previous road at the same point, not going 'downwards' at each step...

Comment: If you have a specific problem with the implementation, you need to explicitely ask about this problem, reducing your code to a [mcve], clearly state what the output is and in how far it deviates from what you are expecting.

Comment: ok, I'll edit the question to reflect that. Thing is that I am very newbie using matplotlib animations so I was wondering if in fact this is possible, but my question in fact is 'how  to achieve this', so that's it

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest edit done...

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly what you want, although I'm not sure why you want to animate the time, since time is already one of the axes in the plot.

The idea here is to store the simulation results of a time-step row by row in an array and replot this array. Thereby previous simulation results are not lost.

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc

# model params
vmax = 5
lenroad = 50
prob = 0.4

# sim params
numiters = 25

# traffic model
def nasch():
    global road
    gaps = np.full(road.shape, -1)
    road_r4 = np.full(road.shape, -1)
    for n,x in enumerate(road):
        if x > -1:
            d = 1
            while road[(n+d) % len(road)] < 0:
                d += 1
            d -= 1
            gaps[n] = d

    road_r1 = np.where(road!=-1, np.minimum(road+1, vmax), -1)
    road_r2 = np.where(road_r1!=-1, np.minimum(road_r1, gaps), -1)
    road_r3 = np.where(road_r2!=-1, np.where(np.random.rand() < prob, np.maximum(road-1, 0), road), -1)
    for n,x in enumerate(road_r3):
        if x > -1:
            road_r4[(n+x) % len(road_r3)] = x

    return road_r4


def plot_nasch(i):
    print i
    global road
    road = nasch()
    #store result in array
    road_over_time[i+1,:] = road
    # plot complete array
    plot.set_array(road_over_time)


# init road
road = np.random.randint(-10, vmax+1, [lenroad])
road = np.where(road>-1, road, -1)
# initiate array
road_over_time = np.zeros((numiters+1, lenroad))*np.nan
road_over_time[0,:] = road



fig  = plt.figure()
plot = plt.imshow(road_over_time, cmap='Pastel2', interpolation='nearest', vmin=-1.5, vmax=6.5)
plt.colorbar()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plot_nasch, frames=numiters, init_func=lambda : 1, interval=400, blit=False, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```